# Use system font with CGContextSelectFont

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

How do I find out the name of the system font to use with `CGContextSelectFont` on iOS?

Comment: On OS X or iOS?  (Not too different, just `NSFont` vs `UIFont`.)

Comment: I need to do this on iOS (edited post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12].fontName
```

However, I wouldn't recommend using the method `CGContextSelectFont()`, since it will be deprecated in iOS 7 on Sept 18th. Here's what the docs say:

> (Deprecated in iOS 7.0. Use Core Text instead.)